# Filter by object key inside array

Tags: javascript

Using the provided example from [MDN (in the 'Searching in array' example half way down that page)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), how do I change this to be able to filter by by object key on an object inside an array? Right now it's getting the error: `TypeError: el.toLowerCase is not a function`.

```js
var searchTerm = "lotty";

var arr = [
  {user: "William", message:"meet me in the nanoscale library"},
  {user: "Lotty", message:"sounds like a plan"}
  ];

function filterItems(query) {
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
    return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

var filteredArr = filterItems(searchTerm);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`el` is the object being iterated over, not the `user` string, so `el.toLowerCase()` doesn't work. For what you want, destructure the `el` into the `user` first:

```js
var newUser = "lotty";

var arr = [
  {user: "William", message:"meet me in the nanoscale library"},
  {user: "Lotty", message:"sounds like a plan"}
  ];

function filterItems(query) {
  return arr.filter(function({ user }) {
    return user.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  })
}

var filteredArr = filterItems(newUser);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Or, more tersely, using modern syntax and `.includes`:

```js
var newUser = "lotty";

var arr = [
  {user: "William", message:"meet me in the nanoscale library"},
  {user: "Lotty", message:"sounds like a plan"}
  ];

const filterItems = query => arr.filter(
  ({ user }) => user.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
);

var filteredArr = filterItems(newUser);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Comment: Thank you. By 'destructure', do you mean stuff the user key inside an object as the filter argument? It's a very neat, simple solution.

Comment: Yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment If all you need is one property from an object, and not the whole object, destructuring immediately can reduce syntax noise.

Answer (score 1):

CertainPerformance's answer is verygood. But if u want to use destructure, you must sure the object has `user` key. like this: `user&&user.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())`